# C++ Array of Struct: Functions aren't working

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct

Hey guys I'm pretty new into coding...
so my code won't run and i don't know what is wrong. 
one of the errors that Im getting is that in my

```
void animal::petDataInfo(animal maxEntry[], int counter)
```

the counter is saying that it isn't being initialized...

basically i don't know whats wrong....

animal.h

```
#ifndef Database_animal_h
#define Database_animal_h


struct animal
{
    char    petName[20];
    char    lastName[30];
    char    color[12];
    int     month, day, year;

    void petDataInfo(animal [], int &counter);
    void displayInfo(animal [], int &counter);

}; animal maxEntry[100];


#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "animal.h"


enum animalSpecies {Dog, Cat, Bird, Reptile, Other};
    animalSpecies getAnimal();
    void print(animalSpecies entered);

void menuInfo(animal [], int &counter);
void petDataInfo(animal [], int &counter);
void displayInfo(animal [], int &counter);
void quitInfo(int &counter);


int main()
{

    int     counter=0;

    counter++;




    menuInfo(maxEntry, counter);




    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}


/********************************************************************************************************/

void menuInfo(animal maxEntry[], int& counter)
{
    char letter; 

    do
    {
        cout<<"\nWhat would you like to do?"<<endl;
        cout<<"(E)nter"<<endl;
        cout<<"(S)earch"<<endl;
        cout<<"(D)isplay"<<endl;
        cout<<"(C)lear"<<endl;
        cout<<"(Q)uit"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n";

        cout<<"Please enter a letter: "<<endl;
        cin>>letter;
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"\n";

        if (!((letter=='e')|| (letter=='E') || (letter=='s') || (letter=='S') || (letter=='d') || (letter=='D') || (letter=='c') || (letter=='C') || (letter=='q') || (letter=='Q')))
        {
            cout<<"Not a valid letter. Try again."<<endl;
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }

    while (!((letter=='e')|| (letter=='E') || (letter=='s') || (letter=='S') || (letter=='d') || (letter=='D') || (letter=='c') || (letter=='C') || (letter=='q') || (letter=='Q')));
    {

        switch (letter)
        {

            case'e': case 'E':

                petDataInfo(maxEntry, counter);

                if ((letter=='e') || (letter=='E'))
                {
                    cout<<"Entry number: "<<counter++;
                }

                break;
            case 's': case 'S':
                cout<<"goes to search database"<<endl;
                break;
            case 'd': case 'D':

                displayInfo(maxEntry, counter);
                break;
            case 'c': case 'C':
               if ((letter=='c') || (letter=='C'))
                {
                    counter--;
                }
                break;
            case 'q': case 'Q':
                quitInfo(counter);
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Try again. \n";
        }
    }
}

/********************************************************************************************************/

void animal::petDataInfo(animal maxEntry[], int counter)
{
    for(int i=0; i<counter; i++)
    {
        cout<<"What is the pets first name? "<<endl;
        cin>>maxEntry[i].petName;
        cout<<"What is the owners last name? "<<endl;
        cin>>maxEntry[i].lastName;

        getAnimal();

        cout<<"What month is your pets date of birth? "<<endl;
        cin>>maxEntry[i].month;
        cout<<"What day is your pets date of birth? "<<endl;
        cin>>maxEntry[i].day;
        cout<<"What year is your pets date of birth? "<<endl;
        cin>>maxEntry[i].year;
        cout<<"What color is your pet? "<<endl;
        cin>>maxEntry[i].color;
    }

    menuInfo(maxEntry, counter);
}

/********************************************************************************************************/

animalSpecies getAnimal()
{
    animalSpecies entered = Dog;
    char species;
    cout<<"Species of Animal:\n (D)og\n (C)at\n (B)ird\n (R)eptile\n (O)ther\n "<<endl;
    cin>>species;

    switch (species)
    {
        case 'd':
        case 'D':
            entered = Dog;
            break;
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            entered = Cat;
            break;
        case 'b':
        case 'B':
            entered = Bird;
            break;
        case 'r':
        case 'R':
            entered = Reptile;
            break;
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
            entered = Other;
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Error: Try again. "<<endl;
    }

    return entered;

}


/********************************************************************************************************/

void print(animalSpecies entered)
{
    switch (entered)
    {
        case Dog:
            cout<<"Dog"<<endl;
            break;
        case Cat:
            cout<<"Cat"<<endl;
            break;
        case Bird:
            cout<<"Bird"<<endl;
            break;
        case Reptile:
            cout<<"Reptile"<<endl;
            break;
        case Other:
            cout<<"Other"<<endl;
            break;
    }
}

/********************************************************************************************************/

void animal::displayInfo(animal maxEntry[], counter)
{

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Pet name: "<<maxEntry[i].petName<<"\n";
        cout<<"Owners last name: "<<maxEntry[i].lastName<<"\n";
        cout<<"Pet species: ";
            animalSpecies entered;
            entered = getAnimal();
            print(entered);
        cout<<"Pets DOB: ";
        if (month<10)
        {
            cout<<"0"<<maxEntry[i].month<<"/"; //if month is less than 10 it will add a '0' in front
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<maxEntry[i].month<<"/";
        }

        if (day<10)
        {
            cout<<"0"<<maxEntry[i].day<<"/";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<maxEntry[i].day<<"/";
        }

        cout<<maxEntry[i].year<<"\n";



        menuInfo(maxEntry, counter); //goes back to the menu

    }

}

/********************************************************************************************************/

void quitInfo(int& counter)
{
   int ans;

    do
    {
        cout<<"Are you sure you want to quit? (y/n)"<<endl;
        cin>>ans;

        if ((ans=='n') || (ans=='N'))
        {
            menuInfo(maxEntry, counter); //goes back to the menu function
        }

        else if ((ans=='y') || (ans=='Y'))
        {
            exit(0); //exits the program
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Error: Try again. "<<endl;
        }
    }
    while (!(ans=='n') || !(ans=='N') || !(ans=='y') || !(ans=='Y'));
}
```

Comment: klayrahx7, consider reading this and giving it another go:
http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Well, that's a good starting point to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line, and watch the variables changing, to see what's going on.

Comment: Don't just say "one of my errors is something like this", actually show us what the error messages are.

Comment: @JonathanPotter oh sorry guys i just wanted to post my whole code. The only errors that I'm getting is in calling the functions. Being more specific the function that is using the struct in my .h file. Im not getting any other errors, just that one.

Comment: The declarations of the methods don't match between the two files, one is `void petDataInfo(animal [], int &counter);`, the other is `void animal::petDataInfo(animal maxEntry[], int counter)`. Same for `displayInfo`.

Comment: And you can't just call `petDataInfo(maxEntry, counter);` since it's a non-static method, you have to create an instance of `animal`.

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf Do i need to use the exact same one even in the function? so does it have to be 

animal::petDataInfo(maxEntry, counter);

Comment: The parameters type have to match at least. `int` and `int&` are not the same.

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf so i added a `void animal::displayInfo(animal maxEntry[], int &counter)` and it cleared that error. The error that I'm getting now is "displayInfo (animal*, int&)", referenced from: menuInfo(animal*, int&) in main.o"

Comment: That's probably what my second comment said. You have to create an instance of `animal`, and call `displayInfo` with this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues I found in your code:

1. You have declared `petDataInfo` and `displayInfo` in two places, once inside the definition of `animal` and once in `main.cpp`. Looking at your code, I don't think you need them inside `animal`.
2. You are missing the type of `counter` in the definition of `displayInfo`.

   ```
   void animal::displayInfo(animal maxEntry[], counter)
   ```

   You need to add the type in that line. Also, since the function is not a member function of `animal`, it can be written as:

   ```
   void displayInfo(animal maxEntry[], int& counter)
   ```
3. The type of `counter` is different in the declaration and the definition of `petDataInfo`. I the declaration, you are using `int& counter`. In the definition, you are using `int counter`. Make sure that they match. Also, the class scope can be removed from the definition since it's no longer a member function of `animal`.

   ```
   void petDataInfo(animal maxEntry[], int& counter)
   ```
4. You are missing the object when trying to access the `month` and `day`. Change the line

   ```
   if (month<10)
   ```

to

```
    if (maxEntry[i].month<10)
```

and change

```
    if (day<10)
```

to

```
    if (maxEntry[i].day<10)
```

I haven't verified the logic of your program. If there are any, hopefully you can track and fix them.